# Why is classical simulation of 1d quantum systems effective?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, simulations

There is a basic argument for why the quantum systems are generically hard to simulate classically. Namely, the dimension of the state space grows exponentially with the number of degrees of freedom. On the other hand I've also seen claims in the literature that 1d quantum systems can be efficiently simulated classically. Can someone explain why (and perhaps in what sense) is this true? This also implies that only the large state space dimension is not enough to account for the quantum complexity. What is a better way to think about it?

Comment: The exp. dimension is an argument why it *could* be hard, not why it *must* be hard.

Comment: What do you mean by 1D  system? For example single qubits?